# cargo build-bpf no such command: `+solana`

Tags: solana-program, cargo

I used the [official documentation](https://docs.solana.com/ru/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust).
Install the latest Rust stable from https://rustup.rs/ .
Install the latest Solana command-line tools.

But when i try `cargo build-bpf` in command line in windows 10 i get error:

```
D:\hello_world\>cargo build-bpf 
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`

        Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
        Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-sdk = "1.17.4"

[lib]
name = "hello_world"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

How to solve a problem?

Answer (score 1):

`cargo build-bpf` is deprecated in favour of `cargo build-sbf`.

Have you made sure that you have the Solana tool suite correctly installed? If not check out this guide https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development

edit: Also try updating to the latest release `solana-install update`

Answer (score 1):

The `solana` toolchain comes with the Solana tool suite, so be sure to run the installation steps at https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#windows

You may need to wait some time the first time you run `cargo build-bpf` or `cargo build-sbf` in order to download the BPF SDK.

Answer (score 0):

`cargo build-bpf` is not supported on windows. See:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/20276#issuecomment-969200122

Support did exist for almost three weeks in 2021, but not anymore.