# My pc system is windows 11. I use `cargo build-sbf ` command but it does`t work

Tags: solana-program, rust, solana-cli, windows

```
$ cargo build-sbf
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`
```

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/8009/116

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cargo build-bpf no such command: \`+solana\`](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/cargo-build-bpf-no-such-command-solana)